# Excluding Tables, Figures and References while compiling a LaTeX document

Tags: tables, floats, bibliographies, cross-referencing

In a long document, I want to exclude Tables, Figures and References when compiling it. It is required to exclude these environments using commands rather than deleting them. Following is a test document. Any help to accomplish the task will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A picture of a gull.}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{gull}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \reflectbox{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{gull}}
  \caption{A picture of the same gull
           looking the other way!}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| l c r |}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{A simple table}
\end{table}

Notice how the tables and figures
have independent counters.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you could speed up for figures at least with `\documentclass[draft]{article}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the great option with `draft` mentioned by Christian Hupfer, here's a solution to really remove the floats. It uses the package `environ`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}

\RenewEnviron{figure}{}
\RenewEnviron{table}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A picture of a gull.}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \reflectbox{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \caption{A picture of the same gull
           looking the other way!}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| l c r |}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{A simple table}
\end{table}

Notice how the tables and figures
have independent counters.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good solution @user124577. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MYaseen208 If you like it and it fullfills your needs, please accept the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this work with `\renewenvironment` as well?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Probably it does, but I had this approach in mind, because of a similar problem I faced, where I needed the float's body. That is what is very simple with `environ`.